# How to move right the extended partition, to free room to enlarge the primary one?

Tags: parted, move-partition

What are the linux commands to move right the extended partition (below) over the 7G of free space while enlarging it as the primary partition with that amount.

Here is `parted` outputting `print free` on the VM:

```
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk: /dev/sda: 698GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number      Start   End     Size      Type          File system     Flags
            32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB    Free Space
 1          1049kB  11.5GB  11.5GB    primary       ext4            boot
            11.5GB  11.5GB  1048kB    Free Space
 2          11.5GB  100GB   88.5GB    extended
            11.5GB  18.7GB  7108MB    Free Space
 5          18.7GB  61.4GB  42.7GB    logical       ext4
 6          61.4GB  71.9GB  10.5GB    logical       ext4
 7          71.9GB  75.0GB  3146MB    logical                       linux-swap (v1)
 8          75.0GB  90.7GB  15.7GB    logical       ext4
 9          90.7GB  100GB   9260MB    logical       ext4
            100GB   100GB   453kB     Free Space
            100GB   698GB   598GB     Free Space
```

Comment: Hi! Please don't post pictures of text, instead, [edit] your question to include a paste from your terminal. Are you asking how to enlarge partition number 2 so that it uses up the 7108MB that follows it in the table?

Comment: You would have to change the start/end positions of the partition table using fdisk. You need to ensure that there is ample space though. Get it incorrect and you will over-write data and quite possible "brick" your system.

Comment: which partition do you want to enlarge?  why did you create such a hideously monstrous partitioning scheme in the first place?   btw, easiest way would be to use gparted - either run it from the host while the vm is shut down, or boot an ISO of the gparted rescue disk in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

full story:

- have installed kali linux inside a VM, the easy way
- after dist-upgrade, the primary partition / , became full
- have enlarged the VDI, on host
- have created new /var, /swap, /tmp partitions in the enlarged space
- have moved the old above 3 partitions in the new ones in /etc/fstab
- have deleted the old 3 and created an empty space of 7G, using parted
- added gparted ISO to VM and rebooted

  - have moved right the extended partition
  - have enlarged the primary partition

system started ok